# In general, are there better computational methods for sums or integrals?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Recently I’ve been deriving some integral expressions of the form

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$$

that can’t be solved analytically, but *can* be converted to an infinite sum instead, say,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n).$$

My question is, for numerical computation, is one of these forms generally preferred or better for calculation? I know this question is very broad, but I’m curious if there’s a rule of thumb that always applies, or if there’s a set of rules for determining which is better for a given integrand, or if it depends on the computational software, etc.

---

EDIT:

Based on an example from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260051/solution-of-the-integral-int-1-infty-frac1xea-x-1-dx?noredirect=1#comment6703990_3260051) recent post of mine:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\left(e^{a x}-1\right)} d x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{1}(a n),$$

($E_1$ is the $n=1$ case of the [exponential $E_n$ integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html))

I might start be classifying $f$ as a composition of products of "standard" functions like polynomials, exponentials, and trig functions; and $g$ as a composition of products of "special" functions like the polygamma functions, polylogarithms, exponential integrals, etc.

Comment: This question is simply too broad. You should attempt to classify the functions $f$ and $g$ which have captured your interest.

Comment: @CarlChristian that's fair, though I'm not really sure what such a classification would/could look like. But I gave a stab in the edit above.